# Who knows the distribution of .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

I have a product (VB.NET / Winforms) I develop on VS2008, based on .NET FW 2.0
It could be installed on any Windows x86/64 machine (starting from XP)

We now have to upgrade the FW to 3.5, and I have doubts whether to include FW 3.5 inside the package (made by Inno-Setup) or just check if already installed, and if not tell the user to download it from Microsoft website.

What do you think the best practice for that case?

Do you know the distribution of FW 3.5 in worldwide? Do you know what's the percentage of machines which are already installed with FW 3.5

THANK YOU

Comment: I think you are mistaken in assuming that .NET FW 2.0 is installed on "any Windows machine starting from XP". A vanilla installation of Windows XP does not include *any* version of the .NET Framework (see [.NET Framework version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history)).

Comment: Well, I wouldn't include it inside the package. If I'm not mistaken .NET framworks are huge in file size. This would make your installer very bulky.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of machines have 3.5.  But that's not the point, there's always *some* customer that doesn't have it.  Particularly the valued XP customer that used your 2.0 installer and purchased the update.

The 3.5 installer is very small, it is a bootstrapper that only downloads the files that are required.  Which can be a lot of them when the machine never had a service pack installed.  Much less if it did.  The bootstrapper adds about 1.5MB to your installer, much less than the 2.0 installer which was about 50MB.  Easy choice, really.